# apache2 not properly installed and not starting in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2

When I installed apache2 I get below error.

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-12-18 18:09:15 IST; 9ms ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 43699 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=127)

Dec 18 18:09:15 rushikesh systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 18 18:09:15 rushikesh apachectl[43721]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
Dec 18 18:09:15 rushikesh apachectl[43699]: Action 'start' failed.
Dec 18 18:09:15 rushikesh apachectl[43699]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 18 18:09:15 rushikesh systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 18 18:09:15 rushikesh systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 18 18:09:15 rushikesh systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**root@rushikesh:/# systemctl status apache2**

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-12-18 18:15:47 IST; 1min 46s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 45201 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=127)

Dec 18 18:15:47 rushikesh systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 18 18:15:47 rushikesh apachectl[45215]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
Dec 18 18:15:47 rushikesh apachectl[45201]: Action 'start' failed.
Dec 18 18:15:47 rushikesh apachectl[45201]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 18 18:15:47 rushikesh systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 18 18:15:47 rushikesh systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 18 18:15:47 rushikesh systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I tried everything to fix this issue, but I didn't fix it yet.

Any idea what could be wrong and how to fix the issue?

Comment: Apache hasn't been installed correctly. Try `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: This: `/usr/sbin/apache2` is weird. Did you try to install/uninstall/re-install?! Did you try to have a compiled version & installed that? If you would try installing from scratch, you can copy the settings if you made changes (`sudo cp -r /etc/apache2 ~/.`) and then try `apt-get purge apache2` then reinstall: `apt-get install apache2`. It looks like one of the steps from the package prevented the full installation. If you tried to compile your own version. You're on your own.